# Node.JS server, WebSockets and HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: node.js, http, browser, https, websocket

I am teaching myself Javascript and am working on a Node.JS app which runs on a users machine, reads and processes data from a locally running game and outputs it over a WebSocket to an HTML based front end. Its early days but I have the basics working and feel like I am learning a lot.

My project so far is working fine when my front end is connecting to a WebSocket on the local machine (ws://127.0.0.1:8080).

However I would like to be able to use other devices (within the local network) to view the same source of data, which causes a problem. When I change the WebSocket URL to the specific IP of the machine running the Node.JS app Chrome will no longer connect as my font end is served over HTTPS and this is an insecure WebSocket connection. (This does still work if I access the front end by opening the local .HTML file instead of viewing the served version, but this is not a real solution)

At the moment, this project is just for me but I would eventually like to make a simple .exe of my app available to others which (correct me if I am wrong) rules out using a secure WebSocket connection, as I would have to somehow certify each individual machine using the app.

As far as I can see, my only option is as to serve the page over HTTP instead of HTTPS and live with the insecure connection message. I don't have a particular problem with this, but am concerned that the goalposts relating to HTTP/HTTP will be moved in the future.

So, is it OK to use HTTP only now? is there another solution that I am missing here or are one of my previous assumptions incorrect?

Comment: You can create a heroku app with your back-end node sockets and it would make use of heroku https/wss without you need to worry about certifications.https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: *runs on a users machine*.. the transport like HTTP is not the issue, the issue is you have realised if you now have 2 or more things/nodes you want to connect and loopback is not working, so you need to look into network design, i.e either make a P2P network or have a single place the connection/data is sent to the rest is trivial client/server stuff, if your expecting incomming data from the server a tcp ws wont punch though NAT's whilst a polling out connction like socket.io will b fine

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am not sure if I understand correctly. The purpose of the website is not to aggregate this data from multiple sources but simply to act as a display for each individual users - I have no desire for any of the data to reach the backend of the hosted website. Just want one device to run the app and a separate one to display the website and the websocket data, but the data itself will never need to leave the local network.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I may be misunderstanding heroku but moving my backend app/server elsewhere is not possible as it needs to get live data out of the game running on the same machine.